# a case of for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop

I came across the following question :

How many times will the following for loop run -

```
for(;0;)
 printf("hello");
```

I executed and it runs 1 time . I am not able to understand how?

Comment: I would say it does not run, because the condition here is `0`, checked before running the code inside. Are you sure you made it properly ?

Comment: Please, specify what compiler and parameters do you use. On my machine with ms compiler this loop does not run

Comment: i think the output is : "hello"

Comment: I guess that you have an extra semicolon: `for(;0;); printf("hello");`

Comment: did u put semicolon after for statement above? If tats the case the code will print 'hello' once and u would get the interpretation (wrong one) tat loop executed once.

Comment: without knowing the full and correct code, it may be that you have things like `#define printf ;printf` around.

Comment: what compiler are you using nishantv

Comment: yes guys i have tested it in turbo c and no there is no semicolon after for loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not execute even for 1 time. I guess you have a bad compiler?

Ok. I think you are using Turbo C ;-)

**EDIT:**

From C99 standard:

> 6.8.5.3 The for statement 1 The statement

`for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 )`

> statement behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the
>   controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the
>   loop body. The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void
>   expression after each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a
>   declaration, the scope of any variables it declares is the remainder
>   of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two
>   expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first
>   evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an
>   expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first
>   evaluation of the controlling expression.134)

It clearly states that condition is evaluated first before executing the loop. Any standard conforming compiler should not execute the loop `for(;0;) {}` even once.

Comment: Turbo C indeed prints "hello" once for the above code! That's probably what OP asked. So the correct answer is "don't use turbo C" :)

Comment: @Neil Printing "hello" once for the above code is certainly wrong which is what turbo C does. Don't downvote me just because you are not aware of it.

Comment: @obounaim Yes, I ran it on turbo c & gcc. gcc works correctly (does not print "hello" even once).

Comment: @nishantv You can't reason out such a bug. It's simply fails to comply with the standard. Turbo C is an old 16-bit compiler with many bugs and I don't think anybody uses it in development. [It's not even good for learning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961314/should-turbo-c-still-be-used-for-learning-purposes).

Comment: Reasons for `[discouraging turbo C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1962710/1275169)`.

Answer (score 5):

Either the code you copied here is not really what is in your .c file or you have a buggy compiler.

Maybe you have an additional semicolon?: `for(;0;); printf("!");`  will print once.

Answer (score 1):

for loops are defined as:

```
for(startExpression; testExpression; countExpression)
{
    block of code;
}
```

- startExpression is evaluated before the code;
- testExpression is evaluated before the code;
- countExpression is evaluated after code;

Decoding:

```
for(;0;)
```

Means

- no startExpression
- testExpression evaluated to false, therefore loop exits.

**Edited** to show correct for loop decoding.

Comment: If the condition is false, the loop is not executed even once. Your decoding "run code" is incorrect because of `0` in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The code as written above will never enter the for loop.

Check the code on ideone [link](http://ideone.com/KDvRN).

My be this not what you have in your souce code, you probably typed a `;` after `for` without noticing it like this:

```
for(;0;);
printf("hello");
```

In that case your program will print "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Since the expression is 0, it is taken to be false. So, in this case the loop runs 0 times.